# Tooltip hover state on font-awesome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying hover on the font-awesome icon to show a text however doesn't work but if I hover on the parent class it shows the text I'm trying to show.

I tried `.fa:hover .tip-txt` which doesn't work, ignore the reverse `display:block` on tip.text and hover state. Don't want to do a jquery for this simple stuff, I there's a way in css just need to call the right class.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.tip {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 20px;
    
}

.help {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
.tip-txt {
    width: 145px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
}
.fa {
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.help:hover .tip-txt { 
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tip">
  <span class="help">
    Help
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
    <span class="tip-txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution.

- Changed `display:block` to `display:none` in `.tip-txt`
- Replaced `.help:hover .tip-txt` with `.fa-question-circle:hover + .tip-txt` (the `+` sign selects the first element with `.tip-txt` after `.fa-question-circle`)
- Changed `display:none` to `display:block` in `.fa-question-circle:hover + .tip-txt`

```css
/* Styles go here */

.tip {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 20px;
    
}

.help {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
.tip-txt {
    width: 145px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
.fa {
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.fa-question-circle:hover + .tip-txt { 
    visibility: visible;
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tip">
  <span class="help">
    Help
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
    <span class="tip-txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution works. A list of what you changed/improved (and why) would probably be helpful to poster and for posterity.

Comment: Agree, but I saw the change quickly and was just missing a + in the hover state.

Comment: :D thanks, is it possible to put a transition effect on a block element?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my answer. With "fade/fadeout" transitions, you have to replace `display:block and display: none;`. @MrNew

Answer (score 0):

U have to change the CSS like this

```
.fa-question-circle:hover + .tip-txt { 
    display: block;
  color: green;
   -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}  
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

because this is wrong already

```
.fa:hover .tip-txt
```

If the tip-txt is directly inside the container:

```
.fa:hover > .tip-txt{ display: block; }
```

If tip-txt is next to (after containers closing tag) the container:

```
.fa:hover + .tip-txt { display: block; }
```

If the tip-txt is somewhere inside the container:

```
.fa:hover .tip-txt { display: block; }
```

for ref https://plnkr.co/edit/4eMdRf5dOx0sNIEYD7Ig

Comment: :( what I was just missing a +

Comment: but is it possible to put a transition effect to show the text even its a block element?